# Compiling PHP from source using Microsoft Visual c++ 2008 error

Tags: php, visual-c++, compilation

First off i want to thank everyone who has contributed towards making this website the great resource that it is today.
OK, Here is my problem.
I am trying to work with id3 tags in php and im using wamp server 2.0i on my vista 32bit ultimate. I followed the steps at php's wiki page on compiling extension for windows machines.(cant post the link).everything goes nice and smooth up until towards the end where i get an error saying fatal error c1083. could not open header zlib.h. I am running the shell as the administrator and not really sure what else there is i can do. But im really going crazy over this. I have followed instructions step by step but some how i am still getting stuck. Here is the link to the text file containing the compiling process.
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0Byjn3U-sXJBHNjA3ZTI1NTktYzlmZS00NjAxLTgyNzYtYTM3ZTRhYmY2NzE2&hl=en&authkey=CL6j7e4D

Thanks in advance,
I'm just gonna bang my head against the wall for little bit more and then either get unconscious or sleepy! LOL

Comment: Why are you compiling php from source? I ask because sometimes people think this is how they have to do it to get PHP to run on their server. Which you do not.

Comment: because im trying to use id3 functionality and as far as my understanding goes there is not a dll file for it as yet. I tried a few dll that said will get the job done. But they failed. although correct me if im wrong and please let me know of any other way that i could achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Wooohoooo, Ok all I had to do was `configure --disable-zlib` and then `nmake`. But now one more thing. I am using wamp server and i tried just copy and pasting the produced folder but wamp does not like it and just crashes. Oops. good thing i kept the old copy of the php folder as a back up (unlike what i usually do). So i guess my question is: how do i use this compiled php with my id3 module? sorry about the dumm question.

Answer (score 0):

The PECL id3 module is listed in alpha and hasn't been modified since 2004, so it is very unlikely that you'll be able to use it in any stable method against PHP 5.3.

Have you considered using the GPL-based getID3 class ( http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ ) which, despite its name, is capable of reading and writing id3 from a wide variety of files and has comparable functions to everything the id3 module ( https://www.php.net/id3 ).